# How to extract numeric part with "e" from a string

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a string like "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05".
I want to extract the part "5.011129178e-05" in numeric form.

I have tried:

```
gsub("[^0-9.]", "",  "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05")
```

but it extracts only 5.011129178 and not the e-05.

Comment: Will the number always be in scientific format?

Comment: You can also use `split()` with `=` as delimeter.

Comment: https://rextester.com/HWBTO91365

Comment: @stud3nt  I'm asking for general case not this specific one. `split()` won't work for each case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to extract the digits and use `eval(parse` to convert it into numeric.

```
eval(parse(text = sub(".*?(\\d.*)", "\\1",  "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05")))
#[1] 0.000050111
```

This should also work if you don't have scientific format representing digits.

```
eval(parse(text = sub(".*?(\\d.*)", "\\1",  "reflectance_scales=5.0123")))
#[1] 5.0123
```

---

You can use the same code without `eval` `parse` as well by wrapping it in `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(sub(".*?(\\d.*)", "\\1",  "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05"))
#[1] 0.000050111
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
r <- gsub("\\w.*?=", "", "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05")
```

which gives

```
> r
[1] "5.011129178e-05"
```

If you want it as a numerical type, then use `as.numeric(r)`

Answer (score 0):

Less straightforward than @RonakShah's answer and using the idea of @lllllIIIIll, you can do it in two steps (without regex):

```r
word = "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05"
numb = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(word,"=")))
numb = numb[!is.na(numb)]
```

and get:

```r
> str(numb)
 num 5.01e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solutions:

```
# Solution 1, string split, unlist, coerce to numeric, subset out NAs, coerce to numeric, 
# format with scientific notation (type coercion to string): 

format(as.numeric(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(X, "="))))), scientific = TRUE)

# Solution 2, substitution of alphabetic characters coercion to numeric
# format with scientific notation (type coercion to string)

format(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", X)), scientific = TRUE)

# Solution 3, string split, digit extraction:

grep("\\d+", unlist(strsplit(X, "=")), value = TRUE)
```

Data:

```
X <- as.character("reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05")
```

Bench-marking:

```
# Install pacakges if they are not already installed: 

necessary_packages <- c("bench")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation: 

new_packages <- necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their) associated dependencies: 

if(length(new_packages) > 0){

  install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)

}

# Initialise the packages in the session: 

lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Benchmark the solutions: 

function_performance <- bench::mark(

  # Solution 1, string split, unlist, coerce to numeric, subset out NAs, coerce to numeric, 
  # format with scientific notation (type coercion to string): 

  format(as.numeric(na.omit(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(X, "="))))), scientific = TRUE),

  # Solution 2, substitution of alphabetic characters coercion to numeric
  # format with scientific notation (type coercion to string)

  format(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", X)), scientific = TRUE),

  # Solution 3, string split, digit extraction:

  grep("\\d+", unlist(strsplit(X, "=")), value = TRUE), 

check = FALSE)

# Check the function performance: 

View(function_performance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just parse it like it's a list definition:

```r
x <- "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05"
eval(str2lang(paste0("list(",x,")")))[[1]]
#> [1] 5.011129e-05
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It's quite efficient, here compared to Ronak's answer  :

```r
x <- "reflectance_scales=5.011129178e-05"
bench::mark(
mm = eval(str2lang(paste0("list(",x,")")))[[1]],
ronak = eval(parse(text = sub(".*?(\\d.*)", "\\1",  x)))
)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 mm            5.9us    7.8us    72889.    2.08KB     7.29
#> 2 ronak        29.6us   31.4us    24103.      280B     9.65
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>